# Persistent static route stops working after VPN drops and reconnects

Tags: windows-server-2008, vpn, static-routes

I've got a VPN between two networks, one home and one office (A and B). Their subnets are: (A) 192.168.1.0 and (B) 192.168.0.0

The two networks have identical ADSL routers. Unfortunately these can only do dial-out VPN. So I've got a Windows 2008 server on Network B acting as a VPN server (ServerB). Network A's router (RouterA) passes through Network B's router and connects via PPTP to ServerB. RouterA is assigned the static IP 192.168.0.40 on Network B.

There's a persistent static route on ServerB telling it to use 0.40 for all requests to Network A's subnet, 192.168.1.0. (route -p add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.40). This enables ServerB to ping all machines on A (and those machines to ping ServerB).

The VPN connection occasionally drops (I'm not sure why - it's set to remain always on and seems to drop randomly). This wouldn't be too much of a problem, as it reconnects automatically and quickly, except that when it does reconnect, the static route on ServerB no longer works.

Route print (on ServerB) shows that the persistent static route still exists. However a tracert to a machine on Network A doesn't use the static route; it tries instead to use ServerB's default gateway (which is RouterB), and fails to find the machine.

Deleting and re-adding the static route fixes the problem - a tracert uses the static route. At the moment, a batch file to delete and re-add the static route is scheduled to run every day. But this is clearly far from an ideal solution!

I hope that's not too confusing. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: "route -p add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.40", first your route is wrong.  It should be 192.168.0.0 after "add" unless you typo'd that in your question, in which you should edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the Routing and Remote Access service on the Windows server? I havent used it myself on Windows 2008 but in earlier Windows versions. When using this service you can manage routes used for VPN interfaces and all network interfaces for routing. Doing this manually with batch files is error prone I think.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am running the Routing and Remote Access Service. Initially I did create the static route in the RRAS, but the route seemed to disappear whenever the RRAS was restarted. I looked into this and found a few articles suggesting that it was better to create static routes using the command prompt. However, it may be that when creating the static route in RRAS I used the wrong interface, or that it stopped working because the VPN disconnected (it's a while since I set it up!).

I'll try creating the static route within RRAS and then dropping and reconnecting the VPN.